# Dynamically mapping user credentials in Keycloak - How to change username to replace hyphen with underscore and pad to 6 chars?

Tags: keycloak

I'm a Keycloak noob. I have an application that supports OpenID. However, the backend system providing into this Keycloak instance has usernames which contain hyphens and some usernames under 6 characters.

Unfortunately, my commercial application that will be connecting to Keycloak doesn't support hyphens or usernames under 6 characters. For example, if I create a user account in the app that is <6 chars, the username in the app gets padded to 6 chars with random characters. I've seen that this prevents login to the aforementioned created account.

Is there some way to dynamically reformat the usernames from Keycloak to what is presents to downstream systems?